Chance of suit combinations in five randomly drawn cards
Imagine you draw five random cards from a standard deck of 52 without replacement. What are the chances that the five cards together meet these criteria:

2 of the cards match in suit
2 of the cards match in a different suit
the last card is of yet another suit

e.g. drawing two clubs, two spades, and a heart meets these criteria.
I thought the answer would be
$$\frac{4 * {13 \choose 2} * 3 * {13 \choose 2} * 2 * {13 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 5}}$$
...but this works out to about 73%, which seems way too high to pass the smell test. Applying a similar method to other suit combinations even produces probabilities above 100%, which is obviously wrong. What am I missing here?
(Ideally I'd like to be able to generalize and compute the probability for any possible "suit grouping", e.g. instead of a 2-2-1 split, find the probability of a 2-1-1-1 split, etc.)

Switching the first two pairs doesn't change the hand.

@lulu I see what you mean, but I am not sure how to adjust for that in the formula. My best guess is to multiply the result by 0.5 to cancel out the double-counting but it's hard for me to tell if that's correct

Yeah, just divide by $2$.  You are counting each good hand exactly twice.

Let's count the full set of possibilities so you can see the pattern.  You then need to divide by ${52 \choose 5}$ for probabilities.

$5+0+0+0 : \frac{4!}{1!3!  }{13 \choose 5}^1{13 \choose 0}^3$
$4+1+0+0 : \frac{4!}{1!1!2!}{13 \choose 4}^1{13 \choose 1}^1{13 \choose 0}^2$
$3+2+0+0 : \frac{4!}{1!1!2!}{13 \choose 3}^1{13 \choose 2}^1{13 \choose 0}^2$
$3+1+1+0 : \frac{4!}{1!2!1!}{13 \choose 3}^1{13 \choose 1}^2{13 \choose 0}^1$
$2+2+1+0 : \frac{4!}{2!1!1!}{13 \choose 2}^2{13 \choose 1}^1{13 \choose 0}^1$
$2+1+1+1 : \frac{4!}{1!3!  }{13 \choose 2}^1{13 \choose 1}^3$

In your $2+2+1+0$ example, you failed to divide by $2!$ to deal with the case that the two $2-$card suits could be in either order.

For $2+2+1+0$, this would give a probability of $\frac{949104}{2598960} = \frac{1521}{4165} \approx 0.365$

As lulu indicated in the comments, the first step is to decide which of the $~4~$ suits will be involved.
There are $~4~$ choices for the $~4$-th suit.  So, reserve the factor of $~4,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that the singleton will be a spade.
So, now you have to choose which two remaining suits will be involved, where your choices are hearts, diamonds, or clubs.
It is wrong to compute this possibility as $~3 \times 2,~$ because (for example) choosing hearts and then diamonds leads to the same result as choosing diamonds and then hearts.
So, the suit-selection scalar should be computed as
$$4 \times \binom{3}{2} = 12.$$
The suit selection scalar can alternatively be computed by reasoning that once you select spades as the singleton-suit, there are then three choices for which suit will be omitted.
This alternate intuition leads to the suit selection scalar of
$$4 \times 3 = 12.$$
